# Smoothing a bumpy power function

Tags: r, graph, plot, bioinformatics

```
library(SKAT)
data(SKAT.haplotypes)
attach(SKAT.haplotypes)
set.seed(3)


power_fun_6 = function(MAF){
  power = Power_Logistic(Haplotype, SNPInfo$CHROM_POS, SubRegion.Length = 5000,
                         alpha = c(0.05), N.Sample.ALL = c(1000, 4000), OR.Type = "Fixed",
                         Causal.Percent = MAF, N.Sim = 50, MaxOR = 6, Negative.Percent = 0)  
}


OR6 = sapply(seq(1, 5, by = 0.25), power_fun_6)
y6.1000 = sapply(c(1:17), function(i) OR6[[i]][[1]])
x = seq(1, 5, 0.25)
d6.1000 = data.frame(x, y = y6.1000)
x6.1000 = d6.1000$x
y6.1000 = d6.1000$y
plot(x = x6.1000, y = y6.1000, xlab = "MAF", ylab = "Power")
```

[image]

I'm using the `SKAT` package to calculate the power of sequence association studies. My `Causal.Percent` ranges from 1 to 5, and my intuition tells me me that the more common the allele (higher causal percent), the higher the power. However, when I plot my data, the power curve is very bumpy. I was envisioning a smooth, monotonically increasing curve. Can power curves be bumpy like this? If so how can I smooth it out?